# How to get a unique pointer address in a minimalist way?

Tags: c

I need a unique pointer address.

I am unsure if I need to give a value to the pointer, or if it gets an address at declaration. Or if I need to initialize a normal variable and/or initialize it.

```
int * my_ptr;
int * unique_address = my_ptr;
```

vs

```
int my_val;
int * unique_address = &my_val;
```

vs

```
int my_val = 5;
int * unique_address = &my_val;
```

Please provide a proof for your answer in the form of a reference to a <= C11 Standard, K&R 2, or POSIX

Comment: An XY problem. What are you trying to do with this address?

Comment: `void * const unique_address = &unique_address;`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by unique.

Comment: Note that in the first case it has an indeterminated value.

Comment: @eric `void * const duplicate_address = &unique_address;`

Comment: @stark: The address is unique; only one object or function has that address.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah yes thanks for reminding me it has to be const. However, can you tell me if the unique address has to be a pointer OR a normal uninitialized variable OR a normal initialized variable?

EDIT: Omg it is referencing itself. Can you explain?

Comment: @devgirl05: The address of any object (or function) is unique within the executing program during the lifetime of the object, except the address of the object may equal the “one past the end” address of an array or single object  immediately preceding the object in memory. If that is a concern, you could use the address of element 1 of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second and third variants would be correct. A variable gets assigned an address when declared and you store that address in a pointer using the & prefix.
(ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee draft, 6.2.4 (2))

Answer (score 0):

If you only want valid address without the underlying object (in the fact you will have the pointer itself).

```
void *foo = (void *)&foo;
```

Your examples:

The first one is invalid.

```
int * my_ptr;
int * unique_address = my_ptr;
```

`my_ptr` does have an indeterminate value as it is not initialized. You can use a reference to it instead.

```
int * my_ptr;
int * unique_address = &my_ptr;
```

Comment: The `unique_address = my_ptr` is indeed undefined behavior and it may even crash if it's running on an architecture such as Itanium. However, the `unique_address = &my_ptr` is wrong (and if you compile in pedantic mode it should be a compilation error) as the types don't even match (`int*` on the left but `int**` on the right).

Comment: @DarkAtom warning, not error. Error if you compile C code using C++ compiler, which is wrong

Comment: If you compile (on GCC) with `-pedantic-errors`, it's an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what the standard has to say on this matter, but I am more than certain that even if you are allowed to do that assignment/initialization without an explicit cast, you are NOT allowed to dereference `unique_address` due to strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @DarkAtom what are you writing about? Read the question

Comment: What I'm writing is not an answer to the question, it's a comment on your answer. The reason I am commenting is because of your statement "You can use a reference to it instead" which is accompanied by a completely wrong example.